# Error in nested IF: Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I have a nested IF constructed like this:

```
if(tt-t(ind)<=t(ind+1)-tt) then
        t(ind)=tt
        y(:,ind)=yy
    else
        if((y:,ind) == 0) then
            y(:,ind)=y(:,ind-1)
        ! If a certain sample point is skipped
        ! then assign previous sample value to it
        endif
    ind=ind+1
    t(ind)=tt
    y(:,ind)=yy
endif
```

I am getting an error saying

```
                if((y:,ind) == 0) then
                     1
Expected a right parenthesis in expression at (1)
```

When I remove that inner IF then the compilation is fine. I can't understand what is wrong with the IF statement. I tried `if((y:,ind) .EQ. 0)` too but that also doesn't make any difference.

The line length is 52 inclusive of spaces and is well within the limit. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the index slice should read `y(:,ind)`. Also, if statements require a scalar logical, so you could use either `all` or `any`, depending on what you are trying to achieve:

```
if( all( y(:,ind) == 0 ) ) then
```

or

```
if( any( y(:,ind) == 0 ) ) then
```